Prestashop user account info in header section of website
I have prestashop 8.1.5 with Megafox theme on it. In the header section I have displayed user information but it looks like a drop down menu and unfortunatly I don't see the username when the user is logged in. How you can see in the picture I try to show only the user name when the user is logged in but... I don't have any success.
In ps_customer.tpl I have that code

 <div class="user-info dropdown js-dropdown">
    <span class="user-info-title expand-more _gray-darker" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <span class="account_title">{l s='Account' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</span>
     {if $logged}
       <span class="register_text"><a href="{$my_account_url}">{l s='Hi, Welcome ' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</a></span>
     {else}
       <span class="account_text">{l s='Login - Register' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</span>
     {/if}
  </span>


   <ul class="dropdown-menu-">
{if $logged}
  <li>
     <a
       class="account dropdown-item"
       href="{$urls.pages.my_account}"
       title="{l s='View my customer account' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}"
       rel="nofollow"
     >
       <span class="">{$customerName}</span>
     </a>
  </li>
   <li>
  <a
       class="logout dropdown-item"
       href="{$urls.actions.logout}"
       rel="nofollow"
     >
       {l s='Logout' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
     </a>
  </li>
   {else}
     <li>
  <a
       class="dropdown-item"
href="{$urls.pages.my_account}"
       title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}"
       rel="nofollow"
     >
       <span>{l s='Login' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</span>
       
     </a>
  </li>
   <li>
     <a href="{$urls.pages.register}"><span>{l s='Register' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</span></a>
   </li>
   {/if}
     <li>
       {hook h='displayStWishlistTopLink'}
     </li>
     <li>
       {hook h='displayStCompareTopLink'}
     </li>
</ul>
 </div>

can someone help me please
I was try to edit ps_customersing.tpl and removing the wellcome message but stil is not working

If you want to display the customer's name instead of "Hi, Welcome", you can replace on line 5:
<span class="register_text"><a href="{$my_account_url}">{l s='Hi, Welcome ' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</a></span>
with
<span class="register_text"><a href="{$my_account_url}">{$customerName}</a></span>
